# What is the clarinet solo at the beginning of Miss Marple June Whitfield Episodes

Tags: classical-music

I would like to know the piece of music and composer of the theme music to the Radio 4 Miss Marple series

https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/b0102h2y

Many thanks
Anna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the opening of [third movement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3EJqvKhYzY&t=1215s) from Mozart's Clarinet Concerto in A major, K 622